# Closing Bezier Path

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics, cg

I am adding many small pieces of lines and curves to a UIBezierPath. But it is impossible to determine which element is added next. In the end the Path is a closed path with no interrupts.

Now I wanna animate an object on the BezierPath. It works, but there is a problem. Because of the fact that I cannot determine which piece is added next to the path the animated object is jumping on the path, during the animation.

Is there a way to create the path so that the animation is not jumping around on it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that builds the path.